# Mobx update a single property in an object

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

I have created an `observable` property in my store as follows

```
class Store {
  @observable values = { id: '', name: '' }
}
```

This observable object is used in a form, how can I reset these values after the form is submitted?

Comment: you can make a field `initialValues` which will be used to override the current `values` on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle)'s solution is good if you don't extend properties to the `this.values` observable. if you do, the `reset()` method will not clear newly extended properties.

Here's my solution to this:

```
class Store {
    const initValues = {id: '', name: ''};
    @observable values = {};
    @action resetValues() {
        Object.keys(this.values).forEach(key => delete this.values[key]);
        extendObservable(this.values, initValues);
    }
    constructor() {
        This.resetValues();
    }
}
```

or even better, to use observable map instead:

```
class Store {
    const initValues = {id: '', name: ''};
    @observable values = new Map();
    @action resetValues() {
        this.values.replace(initValues);
    }
    constructor() {
        this.resetValues()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**extendObservable**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html) and implement a `reset` method on your class:

```
const initValues = { id: '', name: '' };

class Store {
  @observable values = {};
  constructor() {
    extendObservable(this.values, initValues);
  }

  reset() {
    extendObservable(this.values, initValues);
  }
}
```